# dev uncaught exception: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Tags: node.js, monorepo

I am getting the above error

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node index.ts`
```

dev uncaught exception: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000 +0ms
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I tried to find the pid with `sudo lsof -i :5000`
then `kill -9`

But then a new process pops up at the same port again. It keeps happening infinitely so I found the parent process with pid 1 and killed it and laptop restarted.

I am unable to run my node app on 5000. Any suggestions?

Edit: My repo is a node app at the root level and has a client folder which is the react app.

Comment: this happens when you startup the project?

Comment: first troubleshooting step is to try running on other ports, did it work?

Comment: Yes, it happens when i run npm run dev which is, "cross-env DEBUG=dev nodemon index.ts --ignore './client/' -e ts,js"
When I run start script, it just exits out of the command.
"start": "node ./build/index.js"

Comment: Yes , I changed it to 5001 and then it works just fine